# Why isn't the static state on unity affecting the batches number?

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization

I am currently trying to create a mobile game under unity. My problem is that I use objects which are really detailled, but I saw that by setting them to "static" and by giving them the same material, I could reduce batches count and therefore increase the fps. However, setting my objects as "static" doesn't seem to do anything, here are pictures :

[image]

Scene with static objects

[image]

Scene with the "static" box unticked

Thanks in advance for your answers and your time.

Comment: From the official documentation on static batching: "Static batching doesn't reduce the number of draw calls, but instead reduces the number of render state changes between them."

Comment: So how is it possible that the framerate won’t change ? And how could I improve it otherwise than reducing the model tri count ?

Comment: Evidently that wasn’t your performance bottleneck. First step of optimization is to find your bottleneck. There are many possible places to look. There are many articles on the subject;  too much info to explain in an answer here.